# How does one edit and save clips once and reuse in multiple videos with Adobe Premiere?

Tags: premiere

I have many clips which all need basic editing such as adjusting the start and end. I would also like to reuse these same clips in multiple videos without setting the start and end again. I would like a portfolio of these basic edits once and simply use them as is. Of course inside premiere i would edit them again if necessary and so on without affecting the original settings. Is this possible if so how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within a new project, create a sequence/timeline; call it 'Basic Edits' if you like, and make your trim edits on the source clips there. For each of your multiple videos, create a new sequence and copy-paste the trimmed clips from the first sequence.

Or if you want to use these clips in another project, you can import the sequence by the File -> Import menu dialog.

Of course, I presume that by Adobe Premiere, you don't mean Premiere Elements - the lite version - which doesn't feature multiple sequences in a project, as far as I know.

Comment: Thnx will try! i was hoping there was a formal way rather than "messy" copy/paste but the second para seems to be on the money...

Comment: The import option seems to imply all my clips get imported. I was hoping that a panel of "edited" clips could be built up and then i pick one by one without "importing".

Comment: In the import dialog, you can choose to import the entire project or selected sequences. Just gather your reusable clips in a single sequence and import just that. Or if even that's too much, you'll have to create a sequence for **each** source clip and then import just that. More trouble than it's worth, IMHO.